# Image saving do not work if name contain slash

Tags: android

I developing app which send images to server. All image name must begin with scanned code (barcode or QR code) + 5 random numbers.
Everthing works fine if i scan barcode with numbers. But if i scan QR code wich contain slash character `/` then my app explode.
if I parse scanned QR code and replace `/` with `_` again everything works fine.

This is code where i generate image file

```
private File createImageFile() throws IOException {

    imageName = generateImageName();
    File storageDir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
    File image = File.createTempFile(imageName, ".png", storageDir);
    mCurrentPhotoPath = image.getPath();

    mImageNameList.add(imageName);
    return image;
}
```

This is code where i generate image name. Part with replacing characters can be commented.

```
public String generateImageName() {

    int randomNumber = randomGenerator.nextInt((99999 - 100) + 1) + 100;
    // Image name generator
    if (mCodeContent.contains("http://")) {
        mCodeContent = mCodeContent.replace("http://", "");
    }
    if (mCodeContent.contains("/")) {
        mCodeContent = mCodeContent.replace("/", "_");
    }
    imageName = mCodeContent + "_" + Integer.toString(randomNumber) + ".png";
    return imageName;
}
```

i need full QR code name with slashes

Comment: Have you tried to rename a file in windows/linux and to put slash into the filename?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

File name contains slash `/` is raising exception because this char is reserved for directory, may be replace with [Character 'DIVISION SLASH' (U+2215)](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2215/index.htm) which looks like `∕`, or [Character 'FULLWIDTH SOLIDUS' (U+FF0F)](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/ff0f/index.htm) which looks like `／`.

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion it is bad idea to use slashes in filename, because Linux and Android filesystem doesn't allow to use this characters in filename. It may cause serious problems on server side too.

I think that server requirements should be changed in this case.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion you don't actually NEED to name your images with the url of the QR in the first place, that's just the way you designed your solution, but your initial problem probably never involved that by itself.
On top of that you didn't take into account any https:// beginning in your code.

To stay on your request :

- Why you can't do it :

"/" is the character to separate folders in the paths of your filesystem, you can't put any in a filename.

- What you could do with minimal changes :

encode the url so you don't get "/" but "%2F"